# Unexpected behavior of this prolog program

Tags: prolog

So for hw I need to make a program that finds a hole in a list of integers. The integers are always positive and there are no duplicates. Th following code works perfectly and always returns a list containing the hole. But its major flaw is that it only handles integer lists up to 9. I tried to fix this issue with by increment but with no luck. I always get a stack overflow. I cannot find out why. I thought all of my terminal predicates were correct. I have been using trace but the output just confuses me, it continues to increment.

```
  game(Input, Hole) :-
     sort(Input, Sortedinput),
     compareheads(Sortedinput, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], Hole). 

  compareheads([], IntegerList, []).
  compareheads([], Anotherlist, Output).
  compareheads(Compinput, [N|Restofintegers], [N|Output]) :-
     compareheads(Compinput, Restofintegers, Output).
  compareheads([H|Restofinput], [H|Restofintegers], Output) :-
     compareheads(Restofinput, Restofintegers, Output).
```

This is the program that doesn't work...

```
 game(Input, Hole) :-
    sort(Input, Sortedinput),
    compareheads(Sortedinput, 1, Hole).

 compareheads([], IntegerList, []).
 compareheads([], Anotherlist, Hole).
 compareheads(List, 100, []).
 compareheads(Compinput, Incr, [Incr|Hole]) :-
    incr(Incr, Next),
    compareheads(Compinput, Next, Hole).
 compareheads([Incre|Restofinput], Incre, Hole) :-
    incr(Incre, Another),
    compareheads(Restofinput, Another, Hole).

 incr(X, Y) :-
    Y is X + 1.
```

Comment: What do you mean *finds a hole*? Give an example.

Comment: You should try to write down the meaning, in plain English, of the 2nd, 3rd and 4th clauses of  `compareheads/3`.